# view details in tree view from original model (Many2one) - Odoo 9

Tags: foreign-keys, odoo

I have simple database which has 3 models as follows

1- camps (to store Camps master data)

2- players (to store players master data)

3- players_camps (to store camps each player has attended)

the code for all models as follows:

```
class Camps(Model):
     _name = 'camps'
     name = Char('Name')
     organizer = Char() 
     date_from = Date('From date')
     date_to = Date('To date')     
     place = Char() 
     supervisor = Char() 
     notes = Text()

class players(Model):
     _name = 'player'
     name = Char()
     camps = One2many('player_camps', 'player')

class player_camps(Model):
     _name = 'player_camps'
     camps = Many2one('camps', on_delete='CASCADE', on_update='CASCADE')
     organizer = Many2one('camps', on_delete='CASCADE', on_update='CASCADE') 
     place = Many2one('camps', on_delete='CASCADE', on_update='CASCADE')
     date_from = Many2one('camps', on_delete='CASCADE', on_update='CASCADE')
     date_to = Many2one('camps', on_delete='CASCADE', on_update='CASCADE')
     result = Integer(default=0)
```

when I display players camps (using One2many widget in the view ) I can see only the camp name but the other data 
like organizer or place (which are stored in master model of camps) not shown
how can I show this data in the tree view of the players camps view ?

**Edit**: here is view file for players

**Note**: I have removed some fields from players view and its model to make the code shorter

```
<openerp>
    <data>
        <!--Form view -->
        <record id="Player_form_view" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="model">player</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <form>
                    <notebook>
                        <page name="basic_data" string="Basic Data">
                            <group>
                                <field name="name"/>

                            </group>
                        </page>
<page name="camps" string="Camps">
                            <field name="camps">
                                <tree>
                                    <field name="camp"/>
                                    <field name="instructor"/>
                                    <field name="organizer"/>
                                    <field name="place"/>
                                    <field name="date_from"/>
                                    <field name="date_to"/>
                                    <field name="result"/>
                                    <field name="notes"/>
                                </tree>
                            </field>
                        </page>
   </notebook>
                </form>
            </field>
        </record>
</data>
</openerp>
```

Comment: Please show your view file code.

Comment: Odedra view code added

Answer (score 0):

Please remove widget from one2many list and in `<tree>` tag declared field as many as you want to show.

Try with following code:

```
<openerp>
    <data>
        <!--Form view -->
        <record id="player_form_view" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">player.form.view</field>
            <field name="model">spogaze.player</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <form>
                    <notebook>
                        <page name="basic_data" string="Basic Data">
                            <group>
                                <field name="name"/>

                            </group>
                        </page>
                        <page name="exams" string="Exams">
                            <field name="exams">
                                <tree string="Exam" editable="bottom">
                                    <field name="camp"/>
                                    <field name="instructor"/>
                                    <field name="organizer"/>
                                    <field name="place"/>
                                    <field name="date_from"/>
                                    <field name="date_to"/>
                                    <field name="result"/>
                                    <field name="notes"/>
                                </tree>
                            </field>
                        </page>
                    </notebook>
                </form>
            </field>
        </record>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

Comment: I didn't get your point, but I edited my view code in the original post according to what I understand from your answer, removed widget="one2many_list", and same result

Comment: this is what I get https://s32.postimg.org/myykvf4qt/Screenshot_from_2016_07_16_12_51_15.png

Comment: the image shows that all items are still get camp name while I need to get camp details such as date, type etc.. which means when I update camp details I found it updated in players view (the image shows exam which is the same case in camp)